# How to read csv files from the local driver node using Spark?

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark

I had to unzip files from Amazon S3 into my driver node (Spark cluster), and I need to load all these csv files as a Spark Dataframe, but I found the next problem when I tried to load the data from the driver node:

PySpark:

```
df = self.spark.read.format("csv").option("header", True).load("file:/databricks/driver/*.csv")
```

> 'Path does not exist: file:/folder/*.csv'

I tried to move all these files to dbfs using dbutils.fs.mv() but I'm running a Python file and I can't use dbutils(). I think I need to broadcast the file but I don't know-how, because I tried with `self.sc.textFile("file:/databricks/driver/*.csv").collect()` and `self.sc.addFile("file:/databricks/driver/*.csv")` and the process it is not able to find the files.

**UPDATE**
When I ran this code:

```
import os
BaseLogs("INFO", os.getcwd())
folders = []
for r, d, f in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
    for folder in d:
      folders.append(os.path.join(r, folder))

for f in folders:
    BaseLogs("INFO", f)
BaseLogs("INFO", os.listdir("/databricks/driver/zipFiles/s3Sensor/2017/Tracking_Bounces_20190906.csv.zip"))
BaseLogs("INFO", os.listdir("/databricks/driver/zipFiles/s3Sensor/2017/Tracking_Opens_20190907.zip"))
```

I obtained: 
[image]

Then I tried to do:

```
try:
    df = self.spark.read.format("csv").option("header", True).option("inferSchema", "true").load("file:///databricks/driver/zipFiles/s3Sensor/2017/Tracking_Bounces_20190906.csv.zip/Bounces.csv")                       
except Exception as e:
    BaseLogs("INFO", e)
    BaseLogs("INFO", "Reading {0} as Spark Dataframe".format("file://" +  file  + ".csv"))
    df = self.spark.read.format("csv").option("header", True).option("inferSchema", "true").load("file://" + file + ".csv")
```

I obtained the next error:

> 2019-10-24T15:16:25.321+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen:
>   470370K->14308K(630272K)] 479896K->30452K(886784K), 0.0209171 secs]
>   [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.01, real=0.02 secs] 
>   2019-10-24T15:16:25.977+0000: [GC (Metadata GC Threshold) [PSYoungGen:
>   211288K->20462K(636416K)] 227432K->64316K(892928K), 0.0285984 secs]
>   [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.02, real=0.02 secs] 
>   2019-10-24T15:16:26.006+0000: [Full GC (Metadata GC Threshold)
>   [PSYoungGen: 20462K->0K(636416K)] [ParOldGen: 43854K->55206K(377344K)]
>   64316K->55206K(1013760K), [Metaspace: 58323K->58323K(1099776K)],
>   0.1093583 secs] [Times: user=0.31 sys=0.02, real=0.12 secs]  2019-10-24T15:16:28.333+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen:
>   612077K->23597K(990720K)] 667283K->78811K(1368064K), 0.0209207 secs]
>   [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.01, real=0.02 secs]  **INFO: An error occurred
>   while calling o195.load.** : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job
>   aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most
>   recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, 172.31.252.216,
>   executor 0): **java.io.FileNotFoundException: File**
>   **file:/databricks/driver/zipFiles/s3Sensor/2017/Tracking_Bounces_20190906.csv.zip/Bounces.csv
>   does not exist It is possible the underlying files have been updated.**
>   You can explicitly invalidate the cache in Spark by running 'REFRESH
>   TABLE tableName' command in SQL or by recreating the Dataset/DataFrame
>   involved.     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anon$2.getNext(FileScanRDD.scala:248)
>     at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)

Comment: Try to use `file:///databricks/driver/*.csv`. Did you explicitly save the unzipped files under that directory?

Comment: Actually no, I defined other path but automatically the files are saving in databricks/driver/[my explicitly folder path]

Answer (score 2):

You could try to read your data into a panda dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
pdf = pd.read_csv("file:/databricks/driver/xyz.csv")
```

and convert it to a spark dataframe:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)
```

Comment: I tried this solution, but I'm launching a job with a .py file... I imported it from "pyspark.dbutils import DBUtils" but it does not work (No module found). Can you try to launch a job using a py file using dbutils()?

Comment: Got it, updated my answer, phps. this approach helps. As your data is on the driver it should not be a super large dataset.

Comment: How can I fix this error Can not merge type <class 'pyspark.sql.types.DoubleType'> and <class 'pyspark.sql.types.StringType'>?

Comment: I converted the Pandas Dataframe to Koalas Dataframe and it works

Comment: But I have problems to insert data using the dataframe in delta, dbfs or s3...  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find the REPL id in Spark local properties. Spark-submit and R doesn't support transactional writes from different clusters. If you are using R, please switch to Scala or Python. If you are using spark-submit , please convert it to Databricks JAR job. Or you can disable multi-cluster writes by setting 'spark.databricks.delta.multiClusterWrites.enabled' to 'false'. If this is disabled, writes to a single table must originate from a single cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
scala> val test = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").load("file:///path/to/csv/testcsv.csv")
```

Comment: Issue might be because of zip, unzip & try it

Comment: what do you mean about "zip, unzip & try it"

Comment: 2017/Tracking_Bounces_20190906.csv.zip/Bounces.csv - here Bounces.csv is in Tracking_Bounces_20190906.csv.zip, zip folder.I assume the issue might be because your csv files in zip, so unzip that folder & give it a try

Comment: It is just the name of the folder, the csv file is actually a csv file